# Cannot modify a MovieClip filter property

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I applied a Bevel filter to a MovieClip. Later in my code, when I'm trying to change a filter property it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code:

```
for (var i: int = 0; i < myMovieClip.filters.length; i++) {
    if (myMovieClip.filters[i] is BevelFilter) {
        trace("done");
        myMovieClip.filters[i].highlightColor = 0xFF0000;
        myMovieClip.filters[i].shadowColor = 0x0000FF;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what result do you see? Does it go inside `if`? Do you see that `trace` being outputed?

Comment: yes i get the trace but the filter doesn't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this guide from adobe: [Graphic Effects Learning Guide for Flash: Filters](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/learning_guide/graphic_effects/part08.html)

> Each filter has a set of properties unique to it. The filters can be
>   accessed and modified just like a regular array object, although
>   getting and setting the filters using the filters property returns a
>   duplicate of the filters object instead of a reference.
>
> ```
> // This will not work
> my_mc.filters[0].blurX = 20;
> ```
>
> Because the previous code snippet returns a copy of the filters array,
>   it modifies the duplicate. In order to modify the blurX property, you
>   need to use the following ActionScript code instead:
>
> ```
> // This will work
> var filterList:Array = my_mc.filters;
> filterList[0].blurX = 20;
> my_mc.filters = filterList;
> ```

So it seems that you need to change your code to something like this:

```
var filtersList:Array = myMovieClip.filters;
for (var i: int = 0; i < filtersList.length; i++) {
  if (filtersList[i] is BevelFilter) {
    trace("done");
    filtersList[i].highlightColor = 0xFF0000;
    filtersList[i].shadowColor = 0x0000FF;
    myMovieClip.filters = filtersList;
    break;
  }
}
```